# How to get my text to show up In <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im not looking for a straight up answer, but I would love some guidance on my issue. Currently I am attempting to display the text "HTML5  Canavs" in . Though my code looks correct in comparison with many different sites and my work book, all i see is the boarder of canvas without any text. I have used Firefox and Chrome yet both fail to display the text in canvas. Please let me know if I am missing something silly... I really appreciate any  guidance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Exercise 14.5</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="text" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid red;"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("text");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

    context.fillStyle = "green";
    context.font = "bold 28px serif";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText = ("HTML5 Canvas", 0, 0);
    context.shadowBlur = 6;
    context.shadowOffsetX = -2;
    context.shadowOffsetY = -5;
    context.shadowColor = "grey";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple errors in your code:

1. `context.fillText = ("HTML5 Canvas", 0, 0);` needs to instead be `context.fillText("HTML5 Canvas", 0, 0);` because it's a function.
2. Since you've set `context.textAlign = "center";`, and since text draws above the coordinates you specify, your text was being drawn outside of the canvas. Change your `fillText` function to draw somewhere that's on the canvas.

---

**Fixed (live) example:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("text");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

context.fillStyle = "green";
context.font = "30px Arial";
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fillText("HTML5 Canvas", 200, 50);
context.shadowBlur = 6;
context.shadowOffsetX = -2;
context.shadowOffsetY = -5;
context.shadowColor = "grey";
```

```html
<canvas id="text" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid red;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Dang... Im embarrassed I asked, I should have totally caught that! Thank you so much! That works absolutely perfect, if there is one thing I am learning about programming in general, its pay attention to details! thank you so much, I appreciate your time and help!